# Unable to execute javascript in onclick fnction

Tags: javascript, html

1)This Coding is Working..!!

```
<script>

function load_home(){              
   document.getElementById('mainpage').innerHTML = "<object width='100%' height='100%' type='text/html' data='LoginForm.aspx'></object>";
}

</script>

<button onclick ="load_home()"> </button>
```

2) But when i am writing

```
<button onclick ="document.getElementById('mainpage').innerHTML = <object width='100%' height='100%' type='text/html' data='LoginForm.aspx'></object>"> </button>
```

It is not working

Please help me to run Code No.2

Comment: You are setting the `innerHTML` value to a non string value. Wont work

Answer (score 0):

Just add a trigger in the script instead. Use the below code

```
<button id="clickButton"></button>

<script>
  document.getElementById("clickButton").addEventListener("click", load_home);
</script>
```

Also, please see [how to ask a well formed question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I've just seen your second option (the inline code on the element). That is never a good idea for a production environment, similar to the inline style, as it will be hard to find in a large HTML file. Instead, see the proposed solution in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the `'` in the string:

```
<button onclick ="document.getElementById('mainpage').innerHTML = '<object width=\'100%\' height=\'100%\' type=\'text/html\' data=\'LoginForm.aspx\'></object>'"> </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yfce773(v=vs.94).aspx) about escape sequence

This should work :

```
<button onclick ="document.getElementById('mainpage').innerHTML = '<object width=\'100%\' height=\'100%\' type=\'text/html\' data=\'LoginForm.aspx\'></object>'"> Click Me </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
<button onclick='document.getElementById("mainpage").innerHTML = "<object width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" type=\"text/html\" data=\"LoginForm.aspx\"></object>"'></button>
```

But remember, you should use an eventlistener in js instead of inline-js. So the better solution would be

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.getElementById("mainpage").innerHTML = "<object width='100%' height='100%' type='text/html' data='LoginForm.aspx'></object>";
</script>
```